# Remove EditText Text with inputType of numberDecimal

Tags: android

So I am in a RecyclerView with a list of EditTexts that have an input type of "numberDecimal"

When writing the code

```
editText.getText().clear();
```

or

```
editText.setText("");
```

or

```
editText.setText(null);
```

I get a java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String. Yet on the user interface side of things I really need the editText to be empty and not "0." or "0.0" . Also, if the user where to delete everything I would have to handle that exception by (probably?) adding a 0 to the edit text. I would be kind of okay with this scenario but I would really try to find a solution around this.

I realize the code at one point is trying to do this

```
Integer.parseInt("")
```

This causes the error. I just don't know what to do in order to work around the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editText.setText("");` should work as intended and clear the `EditText`. The problem lies in `Integer.parseInt("")` since `""` is not a valid int. Instead of doing this, check if your `editText.getText().toString()` is empty as follows:

```
if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    //do the parsing
}
```

Also your input type is `numberDecimal` and you are trying to parse it as `Integer`, I would recommend you to use `Double.parseDouble`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that the android code was doing it internally, but I was doing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

When writing the code

`editText.getText().clear();`

or

`editText.setText("");`

or

`editText.setText(null);`

the result of `editText.getText().toString()` should be `""`.And then,you can do like this:

```
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    try {
        int result = Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(text)?"0":text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```